# giving string without first two or three letter in power shell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

i want to read a string from a line. The line is

```
 ERROR: file'C:\Program Files (x86)\movies\action\Theincrediblehulk.mp3' is missing
```

I want only

```
 Theincrediblehulk.mp3
```

the code i use to get only that string is

```
Select-String tt.txt -pattern [regex]"[A-Za-z]+\.mp3" -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value }
```

but it is giving me the output as

```
crediblehulk.mp3
```

first two or three words is missing.
Please suggest a better way to solve this. i use [A-Za-z] because name is dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mathias R. Jessen's answer is a better solution, however this answer explains why the original code isn't working as expected.

---

I assume by your `[regex]` at the beginning, you're trying to tell powershell to convert your string to a regex object.  However powershell is actually interpreting your argument as

```
-pattern '[regex]"[A-Za-z]+\.mp3"'
```

If you do want to explicitly treat your string as a regex object, you'll need to wrap the value in parentheses

```
-pattern ([regex]"[A-Za-z]+\.mp3")
```

Although the regex cast is not necessary, so the string alone is sufficient.

```
-pattern '[A-Za-z]+\.mp3'
```

Answer (score 3):

Start by grabbing *everything* in between the quotes:

```
$Filepaths = Select-String tt.txt -pattern "'([^']+)'" -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Groups[1].Value }
```

Now you can use either `Split-Path -Leaf` to grab the file name:

```
$Filenames = $Filepaths |Split-Path -Leaf
```

or `Path.GetFileName()`:

```
$Filenames = $Filepaths |% { [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($_) }
```